# How to not register someone who is under 18

Tags: javascript

I'm calculating age of that person, if that number is below 18 then I want to restrict that user to click that SIGN IN BUTTON..

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitBday() {
        var Q4A = "Your birthday is: ";
        var Bdate = document.getElementById('bday').value;
        var Bday = +new Date(Bdate);
        Q4A += Bdate + ". You are " + ~~ ((Date.now() - Bday) / (31557600000));
        var theBday = document.getElementById('resultBday');
        theBday.innerHTML = Q4A;
    }
</script>
```

and this is my HTML Code :

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="bday" id="bday" onchange="submitBday()">  
<p id="resultBday"></p>
<button class="btn btn-theme btn-block" href="index.html" type="submit">SIGN IN</button>
```

Comment: And what is or is not happening?

Comment: I want to disable that button if the age is under 18..

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem

```
if({user_age_variable} < 18)
{
    document.querySelector('#myButton').setAttribute('onclick' , 'return false');
}else{
    document.querySelector('#myButton').setAttribute('onclick' , 'function()');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create another javascript method to validate age

```
var diff=0;

function submitBday() {
    var Q4A = "Your birthday is: ";
    var Bdate = document.getElementById('bday').value;
    var Bday = +new Date(Bdate);
    diff=((Date.now() - Bday) / (31557600000));
    Q4A += Bdate + ". You are " + ~~ diff;
    var theBday = document.getElementById('resultBday');
    theBday.innerHTML = Q4A;
}

function redirect() {
    if (diff>18) {
        document.location="index.html";
    }
}
```